# What is the best way to implement tags?

Tags: input, input-fields, tags

I am developing a piece of software in java. In one of the inputs, the user should be able to add some tags, just like the ones of this page.

I'd like to find out the best way to do this. Are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: There is no 'best' way. Some may be better than others, but it all depends on your UI and your users as to what works best for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how many tags there are, whether or not people are able to create tags on the fly and any other limitations or requirements you have.

Tags are very flexible things, and there have been many implementations of these.

Even one quick Google images search returns [vastly different options](https://www.google.com.au/search?biw=1920&bih=946&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=add+tags+ui&oq=add+tags+ui&gs_l=img.3...4530.4896.0.5134.4.4.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.img..4.0.0.26VHTexqbAU)!

So the second part of your question: **yes, there are many ways**.

The first part: **that depends on the exact requirements**!